# Displaying Image from PHP Source results in Parse Error

Tags: php, html, image

I am working with a simple script that outputs an image via a PHP script in an HTML IMG tag. The code used to get the image file is as follows.

```
<img <?php print "$width"; ?>src="http://www.cdja.ca/validate/img.php?memnum=<?php print "$memnum"; ?>&type=<?php print "$type"; ?>" alt="">
```

This is perfect and works fine with the existing images. However the organization has recently updated their logo and wishes to have the images updated to reflect.

When I reference the new images I get a PHP warning and the image does not output. The warning I get is

> Warning: Unexpected character in input: '\' (ASCII=92) state=1 in
>   /hsphere/local/home/cdjai/cdja.ca/validate/logo_links/Vice-A.gif on
>   line 1 Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in
>   /hsphere/local/home/cdjai/cdja.ca/validate/logo_links/Vice-A.gif on
>   line 1

Google tells me this is a namespace issue, however I don't believe I am using namespaces in the code.

As a test I decided to see what was being output by the script for the original logo and the new logo.

The original logo gets me GIF output - http://cdja.ca/validate_new/img.php?memnum=150&type=2

But the new logo just gets me the above warning - http://cdja.ca/validate_new/img.php?memnum=548&type=2

If I change the output file type from GIF to PNG - which is my preference - the warning goes away and I just get a parse error.

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in
>   /hsphere/local/home/cdjai/cdja.ca/validate_new/logo_links/Vice-A.png
>   on line 4

I am really stuck about why I am getting a parse error with the new files instead of the output I get with the old files.

The img.php code is below

```
ini_set('display_errors',1); 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
include ("../phpcommon/phpHelper.php");
include ("../quoteadmin/db_writer.php");

$memnum = getParameterString("memnum");
$type = getParameterString("type");

$img = "logo_links/";
$ext = "gif";

/* ----------  Image Versions ----------  */

if ($type == 1){
    if ($memnum == "001" or $memnum == "002" or $memnum == "006" or $memnum == "015" or $memnum == "121" or $memnum == "153" or $memnum == "323" or $memnum == "150"){
        $filename1 = "Life-White";
    } 
else{
        $filename1 = "Certified1";
    }
}

include $img . $filename1 . "." . $ext;
```

Comment: wtf triston that was my favorite part of this whole question..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of including the image, use readfile to send it..

```
header("Content-Type: image/gif");
readfile($img . $filename1 . "." . $ext);
exit;
```

:)

Comment: You have an extra semi-colon on the readfile line, but otherwise this works perfectly.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Don't use include to display an image. If it's an uploaded file, you are exposing security risks that way.

Try the following:

```
header('Content-Type: image/gif');
echo file_get_contents($file);
```

Comment: 1) that's basically the same answer i gave, 2) you explained it wrong. PHP doesn't care if the included file is PHP or not.

Comment: @Pamblam Eh, it's probably good to show 2 different possible ways to do it, no harm there. But you are 100% correct in that the interpreter won't care if it's php, html, etc., in the included file.

Comment: if he would remove the incorrect information i will gladly remove the downvote. i can't remove it unless he edits the question anyway.

Comment: I forgot to mention that using include on image files is a security risk, and yes, you beat me to it while I was writing my initial post.

Comment: Images are no more of a security risk than including other files, but perhaps it's a more *common* risk. Never trust user input, regardless of it being a JPG or a PDF